# Como atribuir um valor de data padrão para um TextBoxFor?

Tags: c#, mvc, razor

Eu possuo o seguinte TextBoxFor

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.data, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control", @alt = "date", @placeholder = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), @maxlength = "10", @data_val="false"})
```

Como podem ver, existe um placeholder que define o que será exibido nele quando a tela for aberta.
A minha dúvida é:  Como eu faço para colocar a data de hoje no conteúdo real do TextBoxFor? Pois, quando eu abro a tela sem preencher o textBox ele acusa que esta vazio, ou seja, esta sendo exibido que a data de hoje está setada no campo, mas apenas visualmente.

Obrigado.

Comment: Já tentou adicionar `@value = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`?

Comment: Boa tarde.
Tentei realizar a sua dica, mas ainda assim não deu certo. Quando abro a tela e faço o 'submit' com o botão do formulário abaixo do campo data é exibida a mensagem de erro (previamente feita por mim) como se o campo estivesse vazio. Voce teria alguma sugestão para ser feita na Controler?

Comment: Percebi que o problema não era em se usar value = "". Isto esta correto, mas por um pequeno detalhe, deve-se usar Value = " " (capital 'v'). 

Obrigado pela dica. Funcionou bem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o [Pablo Carvalho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/71032/pablo-carvalho) comentou, voce deveria adicionar a propridade `value` no seu objeto

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.data, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control", 
@alt = "date", @placeholder = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), 
@maxlength = "10", @data_val="false", @value = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")})
```